# Model expands on moving horizontally in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .obj, 3d-model

I am moving a `.obj` 3D model horizontally and upon reaching the extreme left it expands which looks really weird.

I even tried to change projection from perspective to orthographic and it makes it look even weirder.

```
// simple movement code
void Update ()
{
    transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 3, 0f, 0f);
}
```

[image: When model is in center]
[image: When model moves to left]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's an unavoidable effect of rendering a 3D space on a 2D plane.
>
> The only way to eliminate perspective distortion is to resort to
>   something like fisheye projection, which makes the image appear
>   distorted in a circular fashion. Or go orthographic.

[Edge Distortion on Camera - Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/edge-distortion-on-camera.174454/)